# C++ compare two arrays and display duplicates - Code works now

Tags: c++, arrays

### At last, here is the code that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

bool checkBuffer( char buffArray[], int buffSize );
void parseBuffer( char alphaArray[], char buffArray[], int alphaSize, int buffSize );

int main() 
{
   char alphabetArray[]= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   char buffer[11];

   cout << "Enter the string up to 10 letters." << endl;
   cin.get(buffer, strlen(buffer) );

   checkBuffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
   parseBuffer( alphabetArray, buffer, sizeof(alphabetArray), sizeof(buffer) );

   system("Pause");
   return 0;
}
bool checkBuffer( char buffArray[], int buffSize )
  {
    if(buffArray, strlen(buffArray) == 0)
      {
        cout << "The buffer is empty.  The program will end in 3 seconds. "  << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(1);
      }
} 
void parseBuffer( char alphaArray[], char buffArray[], int sizeOne, int sizeTwo )
{
   int countFreq = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < strlen(alphaArray); i++ )
    {
       countFreq = 0; 

   for(int j = 0; j < strlen(buffArray); j++)
     {    
         if( alphaArray[i] == buffArray[j] )
         countFreq = countFreq + 1;
     }
         cout << "The letter " << alphaArray[i] << "  matched " << countFreq 
         << "    times." << endl; 
     }
}
```

---

I am working on a practice textbook question that asks a user to input 10 characters that go into an array and then that array is compared to a hard-coded alphabet array. The output should display the number of duplicates, if any, per letter. For example:
"There are 2 a's."
"There are 0 b's."
"There are 3 c's." .....and so on.

My code is correctly counting the number of duplicates (or not) between the 2 arrays. However, the problem is that it is displaying the count EVERY TIME THE LOOP ITERATES. I only need it to display THE TOTAL COUNT.
I tried moving the "cout" statement below the loop which doesn't work because it needs the [i] and [j] from where it loops thru the arrays. 
Please point out where my error is, thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>   // using DevCPP editor
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string> 
#include <algorithm> 
#include <Windows.h> 

using namespace std; 

void parseBuffer( char buffArray[], char alphaArray[], int sizeOne, int sizeTwo ); 

int main()  
{ 
 // precode alphabet into an array with null terminating character 
char alphabetArray[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',n', 
'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','\0'}; 

char buffer[11]; 
cout << "Enter the string up to 10 letters." << endl; 
cin.get(buffer, 11); 
parseBuffer(buffer, alphabetArray, 11, 11); 

system("Pause"); 
return 0; 

}  
void parseBuffer(char buffArray[], char alphaArray[], int sizeOne, int sizeTwo) 
{ 
 int countFreq = 0; 
 cout << "This is buffer array: " << buffArray << endl; 
 cout << "This is alphabet array: " << alphaArray << endl<< endl; 

 for(int i = 0; i < (sizeTwo - 1); i++) 
 {   
  alphaArray[i];  

 for(int j = 0; j < (sizeOne -1); j++) 
 {  
   buffArray[j];     

 if(alphaArray[i] == buffArray[j] ) 
 {  
  countFreq = countFreq + 1;  
 }  
 else 
  { 
   countFreq = 0; 
  }   
cout << "It's a match.  " << alphaArray[i] << "   shows up   " << countFreq << "  times." << endl << endl;       
  } 
 } 
}  // end "parseBuffer"
```

Comment: If this is homework, it needs the `homework` tag.

Comment: I stopped reading at "put it in a char array". Change jobs or change schools if that was a serious requirement in a C++ class.

Comment: This is a homework assignment, isn't it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: While I agree to your comment of *actually* writing c++ code. *Changing schools or jobs* may not be as easy or an viable option for most people as it maybe for some, So why not point out the *real* way of writing an c++ code and help solving the problem OP has(We all know you are more than competent to do so).

Comment: @Als: The "I was told to do X" style of the question makes me fear that I might spend 15 minutes hammering out a "real C++" solution only to be told that that's not how "the professor wanted it"... An XY problem, I suppose.

Comment: If you were taught to use [`system("Pause")'`](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) in a C or C++ course, you should *definitely* change schools or at least teachers. (My computer has a 'pause' command that launches nuclear missiles. Good thing I didn't test out your code on my machine.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few main problems with your code.

1. The looping order is incorrect. If you wish to reuse `countFreq` for each character in `alphaArray`, you need to switch the inner and outer loops.
2. You must initialize `countFreq = 0` for each `alphaArray` character.
3. You must increment `countFreq`, i.e., `++countFreq`, `countFreq++`, or `countFreq += 1` for each matching character in `buffArray` INSTEAD of assigning 1 via `countFreq = 1`. What you are doing now is reseting `countFreq = 1` whenever there's a match.
4. You are looping 1 less, i.e., you check up to 10 chars instead of 11 and you seem to be using the wrong size limit for `alphaArray`.

Please format your code and use the for loops properly. i.e. `for(int j = 0; j < sizeOne; ++j)`.

Comment: Hello devil and ddacot,  thank you for helping me with this.  It's 10 p.m. in CA right now, and I need to get up early.  Let me look over the finer points of your replies and then post again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at that.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s;
char c;
char alphabetArray[] =
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
     'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','\0'}; 
int count = 0;
cout << "Enter a string : ";
getline(cin, s);
for(int j = 0 ; j < strlen(alphabetArray); j++) {

for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size(); i++) {

if(s[i]==alphabetArray[j]) {
    count++;
    cout<<alphabetArray[j]<<" shows up "<<count<<" times"<<endl;
}
count=0;
}

}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not solve the problem described. You are missing a loop over `alphabetArray` and using the wrong operator, `=` instead of `==`, for comparison.

Comment: @devil, i missed one equal sign whatever.

Comment: @ ddacot, The operator is a small typo yes but the logic is still wrong. Why don't you run your program and show us the output for the input string "z"?

Comment: @ok ,that was wrong , what about the new program? i can show you the output now.

Comment: It's still wrong but almost there. You have placed a statement in the wrong place. Most likely due to a lack of indentation. And I don't think (OP's description is not too clear on this) you need to print a statement for each character in `s`'s increment but rather for each alphabet in `alphabetArray`.

Comment: @ :D may be. but where to put the statement?)

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to figure out once you realize which loop is doing what. =)

Comment: Hello devil and ddacot, thank you for helping out.  It's 10 pm in CA and I"ve got to get up early.  Let me look over the finer points of your replies and get back with you tomorrow.   -Code Chick-

Comment: Hello again devial and ddacot, my PC is getting repaired, so it's going to be 1-2 days before I can get back to this topic.  And, for the record, this is not homework, I am a recent grad, this is a project question from one of my textbooks so that I can learn more about how data structures (arrays) work together.  I'll be in touch soon, thanks!

Comment: OK, I have changed my code and it's counting the total number of duplicate characters (or not) correctly, however, I would like to ouput only the TOTAL NUMBER OF DUPLICATES PER LETTER and right now it's displaying every time there is a duplicate. Where should I post the new code?

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler solution although this might not be what you're looking for, it is faster and smaller.
First of all, you don't need an array of chars,  chars have int values('A'=65 'F'=70, etc). so with that information it should be clear to you that you can  perform this task in O(n) time

Here's the pseudocode:

```
for(int i=0 to size of your string i++)
{
    char ch is string.at(i);
    ch equal to upper case of ch
    short j = (convert ch to int);
    if( j is between A and Z) then
    {
        count at j ++; 
    }
}
for(A to Z)
{
    display frequency
}
```

Here's the actual code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string data;
    int count[26]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    const int BASE=65;
    cout<<"string: "; 
    getline(cin,data);
    int dataSize=data.length();
    for(int i=0; i<dataSize; i++)
    {
        char ch=data.at(i);
        ch=toupper(ch);
        short j=(int)ch;

        if(j>=BASE && j<=BASE+25)
        {
            count[j-BASE]++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        char ch=i+BASE;
        cout<<"There are "<<count[i]<<" "<<ch<<"'s."<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Malkavian, thanks for the code sample.  I need to look it over and see where it differs from my logic.  I'll post again after that.

Comment: @codechick You're welcome, if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Malkavian!  You are the full-force Coder!  I give you full respect and gratitute for supplying the almighty answer!  I just ran your code and it worked perfectly.  Now, I need to compare it to mine, and see if I can adjust mine accordingly and post one more time.  I will get back with you shortly, thank you again.

Comment: Update: Malkavian, I am examining your code line by line as I need to learn. For now, I don't quite understand: short j=(int)ch; if(j>=BASE && j<=BASE+25) count[j-BASE]++; } }.  What I don't quite get is why the variable "ch" is being used again and what "(int) ch" means exactly.  Also why the "count" array's index is using "j-BASE" which to me means it's the User's input character less 65 or A.  Please advise, thank you.

Comment: @codechick Thanks :)
Let me try to explain it to you line by line,
First of all, in order to understand char int conversion you have to be familiar with ASCII table, you see each character has a value 'A' = 65, 'B'=66; so if you convert a char into int you will get its value. (ex: (int)'A' is 65), J will hold the ascii value of a char.
(ex: If ch='C' then j=67)

Comment: now since we don't have an array of chars, we need to have some sort of definitive range, (0 to 26), if you look at an ASCII chart youll see that upper case characters starts from 65('A') and ends with 90('Z') basically that if condition checks: if j is a char between A and Z.Here are some examples: 
ch='G'
then j=(int)'G' ==> j=71
if(71 >=65 && 71<=90) ie: (A< G < Z)
 then count[71-65]++; ==> count[6]++;

ch='+'
then j=43
if (43>=65 && 43<=90) ==> false

Comment: at this stage count[6]++; doesnt have a meaning all we know is that when j=G count at location 6 will increase. But it should be pretty clear that location 6 represents 7th char in english alphabet. 
I converted chars to upperCase because, lowercase chars stores different values 'a'=97, 'z'=122. 
If you want to convert chars to lower case all you have to do is change ch=toupper(ch) to ch=tolower(ch) and BASE=65 to BASE=97. 

second for-loop creates a frequency table.

if you have a question let me know,
Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Hi Malkavian,  Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I am familiar with the ASCII table after taking Assembly...; )  I think your approach to solving the problem has a lot of things for me to learn from.  Two things have happened since your post:  I finally figured out how to correct my code; and I have an interview for a SDE position with Amazon.  I'd really like your input on some of the points I am pondering about the interview.  I realize this forum is not for job-related topics, so perhaps I may send you a private message?  Let me know, and if not, I'll catch you on the next post, tx!

Comment: Hi codechick, Congratulations hope you can get the job, there is no way to send a private message in Stackoveflow, but you can send me an e-mail to malkavianofoverflow@hotmail.com

Comment: Hi Malkavian, thank you for the email address.  I just emailed you now.  I'll wait to hear back...; )